# Excel userform not opening in unchecked form

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, initialization, userform

I need a userform to load the the checkbox values in their unchecked form. They open with the boxes unchecked but they don't seem to be initializing that way. Here is the checkbox code and the open button code I have.

```
Private Sub cbxAdditional_Click()

    If Me.cbxAdditional.Value Then
        Me.Width = 524
        Me.Height = 238.5
        lstDatabase.Width = 480
        txbxName.Visible = True
        txbxComments.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.Width = 279
        Me.Height = 238.5
        lstDatabase.Width = 240
        txbxName.Visible = False
        txbxComments.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

--open code

```
Sub openform()

Test.Show
cbxAdditional = False

End Sub
```

I clearly am writing this wrong, when I opne the user form it starts in the IF form, how do I get it to open in the unchecked form?

Comment: is `test` the name of your form or a form variable? And is the Sub `openform` in a regular module`?

Comment: Test is the form. Openform is a sub so when you click the button it opens the form. This sheet will have a few buttons, I'm making them one at a time and calling them test as I make them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple userform:

[image]

When you enter a userform, the `UserForm_Initialize` sub is executed. This sub is NOT automatically created in the code with the userform, but you can create it yourself. Any initialization or set up code should be performed here.

In my example below, I'm showing that the resetting of the checkboxes is a separate sub. I do this as a habit, just in case I have to add a reset button or something.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ClearCheckboxes()
    Me.CheckBox1.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub ResetButton_Click()
    ClearCheckboxes
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ClearCheckboxes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Someday I will write code correctly.